# Lua checks library - pcall loses function name

Tags: lua, luajit

I've started using the checks library in luajit for an RPC interface we have.

But the RPC calls use pcall and when a bad argument is passed, checks is unable to obtain the function name.

Instead it throws an error message like:

```
bad argument #3 to (null) (number expected, got nil)
```

Rather than

```
bad argument #3 to (foo) (number expected, got nil)
```

Turned on the debugging cruft.

```
#if 1 /* Debugging cruft */
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if( ! lua_getstack( L, i, & ar)) break;
        lua_getinfo( L, "n", & ar);
        printf( "\tat level %d: '%s' / '%s'\n", i, ar.name, ar.namewhat);
    }
    printf( "\tend of error, level was %d\n\n", level);
#endif
```

Result:

```
    at level 0: 'checks' / 'global'
    at level 1: '(null)' / ''
    at level 2: 'pcall' / 'global'
    at level 3: 'Run' / 'local'
    at level 4: '(null)' / ''
    end of error, level was 1

false    bad argument #3 to (null) (number expected, got nil)
```

So, pcall is called, but null is the name of the function.

Am I right in thinking that perhaps if the function "pcall" is found rather than null being shown at level 1, the first parameter to the pcall function needs to be substituted from level 2.  But I don't understand the Lua API... how would you do that?

Comment: As you see, Lua does not know the name of that value (a function value passed as first argument to `pcall`), so you can do nothing here.

Comment: I am not aware that LuaJIT can provide full backtraces in the same way that the Lua interpreter can.  I could be wrong about that.  But keep in mind that LuaJIT is compiling certain portions of your code to machine code, and it's a _tracing_ JIT, which means that what it compiles does not necessarily have any correspondence with your original functions (e.g., a trace may cross function boundaries). So I would be surprised if LuaJIT could provide a useful backtrace when it _is_ able to JIT a lot of your code. I suspect (null) here means it was inside a JITed trace.